# After rigging with automatic weights, my mesh becomes HUGE!

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, armature, parent

[image]

[image]

Like I don't know why it's so huge after applying ctrl P and setting parent to armature deform with automatic weights.

Both mesh and armature's scale and rotation is reset.

HALP!

Comment: Yep, like I said I applied scale, rotation, and even location. Everything is reset.

Comment: I did import the mesh as fbx from my co-worker. So the mesh may have not been made in blender. Maybe that somehow affect it?

Comment: The scale in other application is much bigger than Blender and is not Z=up. It's the armature that is keeping the character from its actual size. Try this, copy the mesh paste it then Alt+P to unparent the mesh from the rig you'll find a big sleeping giant.